# No rule to make target when compiling linux kernel when needed by certs/x509_certificate_list . stop

Tags: linux, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile the kernel (haven't done this before) I am getting error as in following screenshop

[image]

I have not verified the kernel (did not verify signature) its version Linux 5.10.33 downloaded from kernel.org. There was also a signature there for this kernel.

I like to know how to resolve this error.

If its happening because I did not verify the signature then like to know

-> How to skip signature checking and proceed to compiling kernel to the end and get final output file/files so I can install it (linux 5.10.33)

-> How to verify signature and be able to resolve this error and to have compiled the kernel

Comment: Please copy&paste the error message **as text** instead of showing a screenshot. Show all the commands you used to configure and build the kernel. What instructions did you follow?

Answer (score 3):

For your first question:

> -> How to skip signature checking and proceed to compiling kernel to the end and get final output file/files so I can install it (linux 5.10.33)

Change your .config via the menu config UI:

```
# Navigate to the linux source directory (mine is at the root dir)
cd /linux

# start the editable menuconfig UI
make menuconfig

# Navigate to: 
# Cryptographic API
#    > Certificates for signature checking
#       > X.509 certificates to be preloaded into the system blacklist keyring
# Change the 'debian/certs/debian-uefi-certs.pem' string to ''

# Save your .config and exit the menuconfig UI
```

Comment: You are the men!